# How does the App "Battery Repair" work?

Tags: battery

I just found this App ([Battery Repair](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.ynfo.batteryrepair)) on the Google Play Store, my question is how can it make my battery last longer. What optimazions are they doing? Has anyone tested this tool, does it work?

Comment: reading the reviews it reminds me of a scam application in which shaking the handset to charge up the battery and resulted in a lot of troll reviews... just saying, *if it sounds too good to be true...* beware... :)

Comment: @t0mm13b believe it or not, on AndroidPIT we had a whole thread on that shake-charger as one asked how *that* worked -- and only when someone insisted his phone replaced an atomics reactor (but he now had a tennis arm) the guy who asked got it's a fake... So I basically think the same (too good to be true), though the comments here sound more reasonable then the one I just mentioned. I see no way how it could work. Still curious if someone can convince me otherwise.

Comment: I believe that even there is an app like Battery Repair, it will never repair your battery. I agree with erik that an app can only recalibrate a battery, not repair. I guess it's only a way to increase the volume traffic for that particular app.

Comment: You think another third party application can do better power management than Android?

Comment: my battery was not charging. Left it overnight and only got 47% charge that lasted less than an hour. I installed this app and ran the process, same as above it "found and repaired" bad cells in my battery. When I got home I put the phone on the charger again and it actually charged to 100% this time. Im not sure if it was the app but something happened. I just unplugged it to see how long it will remain on and will get back with an update on active time.

Comment: OK, so, first... "Make sure your iPhone is connected to a feed source"... Second, like everyone else said, that's not possible...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No app can "optimize" or "maintain" the battery in any way as it can't get the necessary access to the hardware -- probably not even if it required root. This app explicitly advertises that it does not. Anyway, the manufacturer's engineers surely have already implemented all the necessary optimizations. There is no way that the app's developers knows anything useful about every phone's charging circuitry and battery that the engineers don't.

In short, there is no way this app does anything useful at all. (It might even be malware, but I don't get that impression in this case).

(Note: the following is probably not true)

The only thing an app can do (on a rooted phone) is to recalibrate the battery. If the battery is miscalibrated the OS might think that it is as good as empty and force a shutdown although there is still a useful amount of charge left. One app that does this is the aptly named [Battery Calibration](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration&feature=related_apps).

Comment: Though that calibration stuff is called a myth in many places (as the battery stats file should only contain statistics on how much battery was used by which app), that's the only explanation making halfway sense. Still I'm not sure whether to believe it or not, also due to the "myth" part.

Comment: for an app (**Battery Calibration**) which requires root, it's desirable to be open-source & audited. The best way to check that the app is not harmful would be to inspect its source code. It's a pity that [this popular and small app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1024867) does[n't seem to be open-source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=53540520). (I'd like to use it, but I won't install it because it's not open-source.) Secondly, being free software (open source) would be beneficial for the maintenance of the app, and its further development.

Answer (score 13):

MYTHBUSTED

I installed this app yesterday with some uncertainty and it detected (and fixed) a number of problems. I then found this thread which made my suspicions even more so. Today I ran the app and it detected zero problems, not surprising since the battery presumably got no new problems overnight. Out of curiosity I set the date to a month in advance and ran the test again, and suddenly there are eight 'cells' with low charge and two inactive! So obviously all this app does is check when it was last run and the longer ago it was the more 'faulty' cells it throws up in a random pattern to make it look like it's found 'faults' which it can then fix.

Don't waste your time, I assume the only thing this does is provide ad revenue to the developer.

Comment: Yes. Infact I tried similar other apps which claimed to "repair" batteries by running them on Android Emulators and they showed "bad battery cells" on the first run!!! How is that even possible. An emulator has no battery :D  I wrote a furious review on Playstore with these findings. Such apps should be banned.